# Hide followed-up edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

It often happens that the same user edits a page multiple times.  For example:

[image]

What happens when the last edit is approved before the first one?
Would it make sense to hide previous edits?

(Always seem to be tag wiki edits.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are edits for two different things. The first is the [full tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cdn/info), the second is the excerpt which is [displayed on the tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cdn). So it doesn't matter which order they are approved in.

Comment: Cool, didn't know that.  Perhaps they could be paired up?

Comment: @Andomar I was originally confused by the same thing, so it might not be a bad idea.